# "C" split string by space with delimiter but escape space between certain words (last, first name)

Tags: c, delimiter

I want to check input commands from user 
such as:

`add person relation person   (person can be for example John, or "John Smith")`

example: `add John Smith brother Jack Smith`
...

I used delimiter (space) to split string into mult. strings, but I have to leave name of person as one string/parameter (between first and last name of person could be 1 space or more , in each case I have to use interpret it as one parameter).

`// input from cmd stored in "input" variable with fgets() in main function...`

```
char inputTerminalCommands(char *input) // takes char input from main, splits strings and then should compare type of command from user
{

int i = 0;
char *str = input;      
char *split = strtok(str, " ");  // split string into words after "space"

char *array[6];

while(split!= 0)
{
    array[i++] = split;
    split = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

return 0;
```

With my code I split strings by space, but how to ignore space between names? 
or to say, store strings between "add" and "relation" in one string and after "relation" also in one string...

Comment: i forgot to mention, gender of person is also included , example :             `add John Smith [m] brother Jack Smith [m] `   [m] and [f] are for male and female genders...

Comment: You need to decide that it is a keyword for you. You can store them as global and check every output of the `strtok` to decide what is the current token. Then do something according to it

Comment: Your input syntax is flawed. Answer this for yourself: How is the program supposed to know if a space is between name-parts or other tokens?

Comment: @NanonA and hope that that keyword isn't something that might turn up in someone's name... :)

Comment: Are you really confused.. what do you want to do really...

Comment: @NanonA That's quite error-prone and am XY-solution.

Comment: @Alnitak Well it is a start point to go:P

Comment: @Totenkoph93 Does every entry look like this: `add person [gender] relation person [gender]`?

Comment: @sas i am bit confused , here is short summary of what i have to do. the assignment is about creating family tree. in this part of exercise i want to take input from user ( input are commands from user) and first decide which command user wrote. commands are: 1st:  add person [gender] relation person [ gender] , 2nd: draw person [file_name] and few more... for now i just want to read input and use strcmp() to find which command has been called. But in assignment is specified that : all comands are case sensitive, parameters are separated by one space. One parameter can contain space (ex: Name)

Comment: @sas and also, if one parameter has more spaces, it should be counted as one parameter. Maybe for now i just need to find which command user wrote and make another function for that specific command where i can write all of the requirements ( functionality of that command) for it...

Comment: @user3121023  yes, names with upper case and other words with lower case

Comment: @NanonA there are other type of entries:  `add person [gender] relation person ` ; `draw-all file-name` ( filename not separated by space ex: family-tree) `draw person file-name` ; `relationship person 1 person 2`

Comment: Okay, let me give you one example. The example may not be appropriate for your case but try to grasp the idea. Let's assume command `add` is read. What you can do is as follows: you can use `strtok` until first white space. Then you can use `strtok` until `[` which gives you the name. Then you can parse until `]` which gives you gender.Then parse until white space which gives you relation. Then parse until `[` this gives you name and so on. I hope it help. I was writing in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `strchr` you can iterate through the string, parsing command name gender relation sex. This will fail if there are more than one space between words but additional logic could be added to accommodate multiple spaces. It also fails if the format `command name relation name` is not observed but again additional logic could be added to handle that.
Checks need to be added to handle a failure of `malloc`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct parse {
    char *command;
    char *name;
    char gender;
    char *relation;
    char *identity;
    char sex;
};


int main(void)
{
    //char input[] = "add John Smith III [m] brother David William Smith [m]";
    char input[] = "add John Smith III brother David William Smith";
    char *start = NULL;
    char *stop = NULL;
    int span = 0;
    struct parse item;
    //parse command - one word
    start = input;
    if ( ( stop = strchr ( start, ' '))) {
        span = stop - start;
        item.command = malloc ( span + 1);
        memmove ( item.command, start, span);
        item.command[span] = '\0';
    }
    //parse name - could be many words, each begins with upper case
    start = stop + 1;
    stop = start;;
    while ( ( stop = strchr ( stop, ' '))) {
        if ( !isupper( *(stop + 1))) {
            span = stop - start;
            item.name = malloc ( span + 1);
            memmove ( item.name, start, span);
            item.name[span] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        stop = stop + 1;
    }
    //optional - parse gender - one character in []
    start = stop;
    item.gender = '*';
    if ( *(start + 1) == '[') {
        item.gender = *(start + 2);
        stop = strchr ( start + 1, ' ');
    }
    //parse relation - one word
    start = stop + 1;
    if ( ( stop = strchr ( start, ' '))) {
        span = stop - start;
        item.relation = malloc ( span + 1);
        memmove ( item.relation, start, span);
        item.relation[span] = '\0';
    }
    //parse name - could be many words, each begins with upper case
    start = stop + 1;
    stop = start;;
    while ( ( stop = strchr ( stop, ' '))) {
        if ( !isupper( *(stop + 1))) {
            span = stop - start;
            item.identity = malloc ( span + 1);
            memmove ( item.identity, start, span);
            item.identity[span] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        stop = stop + 1;
    }
    if ( !stop) { // if nothing follows identity...strchr failed on last name
        span = strlen ( start);
        item.identity = malloc ( span + 1);
        memmove ( item.identity, start, span);
        item.identity[span] = '\0';
        stop = start + span;
    }
    //optional - parse sex - one character in []
    start = stop;
    item.sex = '*';
    if ( *(start + 1) == '[') {
        item.sex = *(start + 2);
    }

    printf ( "%s\n", item.command);
    printf ( "%s\n", item.name);
    printf ( "%c\n", item.gender);
    printf ( "%s\n", item.relation);
    printf ( "%s\n", item.identity);
    printf ( "%c\n", item.sex);

    free ( item.command);
    free ( item.name);
    free ( item.relation);
    free ( item.identity);

    return 0;
}
```